# Empty values issue SSRS Report Builder chart

Tags: reporting-services, linechart, reportbuilder

[Click for image with line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhqsd.png)

[image]

Edit for clarity: I have empty values in my series. I want SSRS to draw a *direct* line between the existing data points. Empty values is set to "average" and results in the stepped lines shown in the image.

I want it to look like this: [Same data charted in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6za81.png)

Here is my data [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tjCe.png)

Original post:

I have a line chart with three series in Report Builder. Two of the series have null values between points. At first I could not get the lines to show at all, but after searching, I set the empty points color to match the series color. Now it is showing the lines but they are squiggly, not straight lines between each point.

I have searched the site but am unable to find a post with this exact issue.

Comment: just change the chart type from "Smooth line" to "Line"

Comment: That just does the same thing but more angular. Will add pic of that to OP.

Comment: Your question sounded like it was asking how to show straight lines instead of smooth lines. You probably need to edit your question and show the data you are working with and any expressions you have used to try to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I edited to hopefully explain better and added a ss of my data. I haven't tried any expressions as I couldn't find any examples of what I needed to do. I'm fairly new to Report Builder

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly. For future questions, please add data as text, or better still, a script to generate the data so that people who want to help can copy/paste it rather than having to manually type it in to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of an SSRS oddity. The solution is simple. You need to choose a colour for the "EmptyPoint" property of each series. I think this should be the default but there you have it..

Click on the first series, then go to the properties pane (F4 from Visual Studio or View/Properties from Report Builder).

Expand the "EmptyPoint" section  and choose a colour.

Repeat for each series.

See below

[image]

Here's the final output.

[image]

For further into see the SSRS Documentation.

[Add empty points to a chart in a paginated report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-empty-points-to-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Hi Alan, I did see that in the documentation and set color values (before that the chart was just blank), but what is the X Value field under each series in your image in the chart data? Is that an expression I'm missing to get it to draw the lines properly?

Thank you for your patience in explaining how to post questions :)

Comment: That "X Value" will be generated automatically when you setup the chart, I can't remember exactly what triggers it, it might be adding additional series or might be when I set the X-Axis properties to "Scalar (Numbers/Dates)". I didn't add this by hand.

Comment: Ok. I set the X-Axis to Scalar, and that fixed the issue. I don't know why! But I will file that away in my brain. Thank you for your patience and especially for posting the screenshot because that's how I saw my values screen was different than yours.

Comment: No problem. it's a combination of setting the emptypoint color property and the axis to scalar that is the trick. If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted (Check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This helps others find similar questions that have been answered.